Civimail: emails will neither save (draft) nor send test -- DB Error: Unknown Error
Finally have Civi 5.73.3 (Drupal 10) up and running.  Was able to import contacts from another database, search for contacts, create a group and smart group, etc.
But when I try to send create a mailing, both "Save draft" and "Send Test" result in DB Error: Unknown Error.  This isn't creating any error logs in my Drupal reports -- although other Civi errors do.
Also worth noting: The drafts ARE in fact saving in my draft mailings section.  However test emails are not sending.
I have made sure to enter a recipient group, which has historically been the glitch here, but with everything filled out, same error.
One note:  my Drupal installation is unhappy that civicrm_install_canary does not have a primary key.  This table seems to be empty, may I delete it?  Not sure if this is related to my mail problem or totally distinct, but wanted to mention it.
Thanks in advance!
-tiffani

what are your settings at /civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1

Allow mail from logged in contact YES
Select mailer: mail()

You can ignore the canary warning, but don't delete the table. In recent drupal installs you're likely to have the isolation set to something that will work in a basic civi install, but has this warning. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/system-requirements/setting-the-mysql-transaction-isolation-level. You can add an arbitrary primary key to the table though to make the warning go away.

Are you able to send a "regular" email as opposed to a bulk mailing, e.g. Contacts - New Email?

I can!  Individual email works.

Also, thank you.  I designated the ID column as the primary key for the canary table and that solved the error.

will one of you add the above as an Answer

@peterdnz -- I've solved the canary table part, but not the Civimail part.  Anyone have thoughts on that?  I can send groups of 50 through regular mail, but whenever try to send through Civimail I get the "DB error" dropdown.  Same response when I try to send a draft.
Is this something in my Civimail settings if the regular mail function is working? Thanks!
